# Find a form with Java and htmlUnit

Tags: java, html, htmlunit

I have written a simple program which should login via a form on a website.

Unfortunately, the form in the html has no name or id.

I use the latest version of HtmlUnit and Java 11.

I tried to find the form with the .getForms () method, but without success.

[Html Snippet from Website i try to login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0fEr.png)

Here is my code to find the form:

```
    //Get the form
     HtmlForm form = LoginPage.getFormByName("I tried several options here");
    //Get the Submit button
    final HtmlButton loginButton = form.getButtonByName("Anmelden");
    //Get the text fields for password and username
    final HtmlTextInput username = form.getInputByName("text");
    final HtmlTextInput password = form.getInputByName("password");
```

Whatever I tried, I didn't find any form.

This is my connection class if it helps:

```
 public HtmlPage CslPlasmaConnection(){
    //Create Webclient to connect to CslPlasma
    WebClient CslPlasmaConnection = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.BEST_SUPPORTED);
    //helper variable ini with null
    HtmlPage CslPlasmaLoginPage = null;
    //Get the content from CslPlasma

    try {
        CslPlasmaLoginPage = CslPlasmaConnection.getPage(URL);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Return CslPlasma Login Page
    return CslPlasmaLoginPage;
}
```

Comment: HtmlUnit 4.9 was never available - the current version is 2.34.0.

Comment: Excuse me. I messed it up with Junit. I am using the latest version of HtmlUnit

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the page i can only guess...

Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54188201/4804091

And try to use the latest page (maybe there is some js that creates the form).

```
    webClient.getPage(url);
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);

    HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getCurrentWindow().getEnclosedPage();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure this is the only form on the page or you know which form number it is, you can use `page.getForms()` to get all forms of the page and get yours from the resulting list.

Like so:

```
HtmlForm form = LoginPage.getForms().get(0); // if it's the only form, its index is 0
```

Comment: it is not working. throws "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0"

Comment: I have already tried it with a list <HtmlForm>, unfortunately without success. It looks like no form is found.

Comment: Odd stuff, can you give the link to the page?